# Convert from azure premium storage to standard storage disk without data loss risk

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a query regarding my Azure instance. According to the Azure billing calculator.

For premium storage of 2 disk  it costs around 39.42 USD where as for the standard storage it costs around 3.04 USD.

So currently i have azure premium storage and want to migrate to standard disk storage in order to reduce the cost. Can someone suggest me a workaround for this given the condition i don't want data loss to happen on migrating.

Answer (score 4):

Add another answer to [@Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri)'s. If your Disk is managed, you can take following steps.
Now, Azure can let you change your **Managed Disk** type easily.

**Steps**:Go to Azure Portal> Stop (deallocate) your VM> Go to Your Disk> Account type > Choose standard (HDD)> Click Save

Then your disk will be successfully updated!

[image]

If your Disk is unmanaged, you can take [@Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri)'s answer to migrate your Disk.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that. Reading more about it here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-disk-storage, it seems this option is only available for managed disks. For unmanaged disks, you would have to convert them to managed disks first. If my understanding is correct, you may want to include this caveat in your answer.

Comment: @GauravMantri , yeah, this solution is for managed disk. For umanaged disk, we cannot change disk type. I have updated my answer .Thank you for your reminder.

Answer (score 3):

You can't convert a `Premium` storage account to a `Standard` storage account.

What you will need to do is create a new storage account (or use an existing storage account) and copy the blobs holding the disks from Premium account to Standard account. You could use [`AzCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) or `PowerShell Cmdlets` to copy blobs from one storage account to another. If you're using AzCopy, you can use following command:

```
AzCopy /Source:https://sourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1 
/Dest:https://destaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2 /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /S
```

Also, please note that copying blobs across storage accounts is an asynchronous operation so please ensure that you don't delete the blobs from your Premium account until they are copied completely in target storage account.